# How to make utf-8 work with dompdf?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have just work with laravel 5, and now I want to use dompdf to work with laravel 5 too. Surely, I can use it to convert my html to pdf successfully. But the problem I encounter is about UTF-8. I can only get English language, but not my own language.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>លីណា</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function pdf()
{
    $html = view('pdfs.pdf')->render();
    return PDF::load($html)->filename('lina.pdf')->show();
}
```

Comment: Did u find any solution to this? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
public function pdf()
{
    $html = view('pdfs.pdf')->render();
    // i'm assuming here that $html is a string containing your html code and 
    // all characters ARE already utf-8
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
    return PDF::load($html)->filename('lina.pdf')->show();
}
```

Comment: Could be the pdf font. Are you using something specific? try `{ font-family: DejaVu Sans}`. I had the same error and this worked

Comment: I used PDF Reader. I have try to use font-family as you mentioned, but I still get the same error.

Comment: This line makes the real magic:

`$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');`

Thanks Alex